# Invalid Timezone exception when trying to convert datetime 9999-12-31T23:00:00.0000000Z

Tags: .net, vb.net, date

```
acc = 9999-12-31T23:00:00.0000000Z
dim date as dateTime= dateTime.parse(acc.toString(),cultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Please do not use class names (e.g. Date) for variable names. If you change that and it still does not work, it would be helpful if you could [edit] your question with the updated code.

Comment: OK, now please copy-and-paste the code from Visual Studio into the question - it cannot look like that in VS. If you start a line with four spaces then it formats it as code. What is the type of the variable `acc`?

Comment: As suggested, please post the actual code, not an approximation that wouldn't compile. Small differences in code can mean a big difference in the problems caused so we need accurate information. Also, a title and a couple of line of code is not an adequate question. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, as described in the Help Center for this site, and a title that provides a summary of the problem.

Comment: Whatever `acc` is, generating a string from it using the *current* culture and then trying to parse it back using the US culture is bound to fail *unless* the current culture is en-US

Comment: If  you want to convert a DateTimeOffest to DateTime, you can use the [DateTimeOffset.LocalDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.localdatetime?view=netframework-4.8) or [DateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.utcdatetime?view=netframework-4.8) properties

Comment: `Dim acc As String = "9999-12-31T23:00:00.0000000Z" Dim parsedDate As DateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(acc, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. Parses it to `{12/31/9999 11:00:00 PM +00:00}`. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is OK.

Comment: `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is OK because it completely ignores the current Thread Culture (or System culture), using the culture-invariant settings (which *just happen* to derive from the en-US ones). It will be parsed correctly no matter what the current System/Thread culture. What the parser cannot decide by itself is what the offset indicates, if it's not the default, so you have to specify it yourself, if needed, using the overload that accepts a `DateTimeStyles` argument.